# How to address Port names (PORTB etc) in an array (arduino uno)

Tags: arduino

Is it possible to put the names of ports in an array?

I'm looking something like:

```
const ??? my_ports_config[8]= { PORTB, PORTD, PORTB, PORTB, PORTD, PORTB, PORTB, PORTD };
```

So to do (direct register bit set):

```
my_ports_config[i] |= _BV(7);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
volatile byte* const my_ports_config[8]= { &PORTB, &PORTD, &PORTB, &PORTB, &PORTD, &PORTB, &PORTB, &PORTD };
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.  The `PORTB` name is nothing but a handy alias, a `#define` for an address on the chip.  Depending on the Arduino model, that can vary of course.  The easiest way to learn these addresses is to study the datasheet for the microcontroller part on your device.  In the Atmel documentation they're always listed late in the document in a chapter called "Register Summary."  But for the Uno I think you need the  [328P datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) Check out page 615.  The 328 only has ports B C and D though, so actually setting the ports directly will probably take fewer instructions.